# Making Linq To SQL DRY

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

We decided to use Linq To SQL for our Data Layer on our most recent project.  We have a functional solution, that so far has handled everything we have thrown at it, with one major problem.  We have to code the same method over and over again to retrieve just slightly different result sets from our database.

As an example:

```
        public List<TeamBE> GetTeamsBySolutionID(Guid SolutionID)
        {
            List<TeamBE> teams = new List<TeamBE>();

            Esadmin db = new Esadmin(_connectionString);

            var qry = (from teamsTable in db.Teams
                       join solutionsTable in db.Solutions on teamsTable.SolutionID equals solutionsTable.SolutionID
                       where teamsTable.SolutionID == SolutionID
                       select new { teamsTable, solutionsTable.SolutionName });

            foreach (var result in qry)
            {
                TeamBE team = new TeamBE();

                team.TeamID = result.teamsTable.TeamID;
                team.Description = result.teamsTable.Description;
                team.Status = result.teamsTable.Status;
                team.LastModified = result.teamsTable.LastModified;
                team.SolutionID = result.teamsTable.SolutionID;
                team.SolutionName = result.SolutionName;
                team.Name = result.teamsTable.Name;
                team.LocationLevel = result.teamsTable.LocationLevel;
                team.AORDriven = result.teamsTable.AoRDriven;
                team.CriteriaID = result.teamsTable.CriteriaID ?? Guid.Empty;

                teams.Add(team);
            }
            return teams;
        }

        public TeamBE GetTeamByID(Guid TeamID)
        {
            Esadmin db = new Esadmin(_connectionString);
            TeamBE team = new TeamBE();

            var qry = (from teamsTable in db.Teams
                       join solutionsTable in db.Solutions on teamsTable.SolutionID equals solutionsTable.SolutionID
                       where teamsTable.TeamID == TeamID
                       select new { teamsTable, solutionsTable.SolutionName }).Single();

            team.TeamID = qry.teamsTable.TeamID;
            team.Description = qry.teamsTable.Description;
            team.Status = qry.teamsTable.Status;
            team.LastModified = qry.teamsTable.LastModified;
            team.SolutionID = qry.teamsTable.SolutionID;
            team.SolutionName = qry.SolutionName;
            team.Name = qry.teamsTable.Name;
            team.LocationLevel = qry.teamsTable.LocationLevel;
            team.AORDriven = qry.teamsTable.AoRDriven;
            team.CriteriaID = qry.teamsTable.CriteriaID ?? Guid.Empty;

            return team;
        }
```

And on and on ad nauseum.

Is there is a way to pass Linq results as a parameter to a function, so I can place my object mappings in one function, and not repeat myself so much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick stab at it.  Probably doesn't compile (Especially the "from teamsTalbe in teams), but the idea is you can factor out something that returns an IQueryable<>.  You're IQueryable returns an anonymous type though, which wouldn't work.  So you may need to create an explicit type to use in place of 'select new { teamsTable, solutionsTable.SolutionName }'

```
    public List<TeamBE> GetTeamsBySolutionID(int solutionID)
    {
        Esadmin db = new Esadmin(_connectionString);
        return GetTeamsBy(db, _GetTeamsBySolutionID(db, solutionID));
    }

    IQueryable<Team> _GetTeamsBySolutionID(Esadmin db, int solutionID)
    {
        return from teamsTable in db.Teams
               where teamsTable.SolutionID == SolutionID
               select teamsTable;
    }

    List<TeamBE> GetTeamsBy(Esadmin db, IQueryable<Team> teams)
    {
        List<TeamBE> teams = new List<TeamBE>();

        var qry = (from teamsTable in teams
                   join solutionsTable in db.Solutions on teamsTable.SolutionID equals solutionsTable.SolutionID
                   select new { teamsTable, solutionsTable.SolutionName });

        foreach (var result in qry)
        {
            TeamBE team = new TeamBE();

            team.TeamID = result.teamsTable.TeamID;
            team.Description = result.teamsTable.Description;
            team.Status = result.teamsTable.Status;
            team.LastModified = result.teamsTable.LastModified;
            team.SolutionID = result.teamsTable.SolutionID;
            team.SolutionName = result.SolutionName;
            team.Name = result.teamsTable.Name;
            team.LocationLevel = result.teamsTable.LocationLevel;
            team.AORDriven = result.teamsTable.AoRDriven;
            team.CriteriaID = result.teamsTable.CriteriaID ?? Guid.Empty;

            teams.Add(team);
        }
        return teams;
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking to do, but how to I create that explicit type when there is nothing generated by SQL Metal to match it.

Comment: Just create a class with public properties for the two parts you have.  When you create the object, use the default constructor with property initializers (do not take the properties as constructor parameters otherwise the expression can't be mapped to an IQueryable)

Comment: I'd like to see this in action, do you know of any resources or tutorials on this sort of thing?

Comment: Any good LINQ book, pay attention to the parts about deferred execution (to know how to use IQueryable<> vs IEnumerable<>)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could declare your `qry` variable as `IEnumerable<YourDataTypeEntity>` and pass that to a method.  I tend to like doing it as a constructor:

```
class MyDataType
{
  public MyDataType() {}
  public MyDataType(MyDataTypeEntity mdte)
  {
    // set properties and fields here
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: That's good information, and will work when I am pulling from just a single table, or stored procedure.  But notice that I do a join in my linq statements, so I have the SolutionName value ready to go in my objects.  What type would I use for that.

Comment: I've had a few simple cases of that problem, and I usually worked around it by implementing a view in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass out an IQueryable then when you want to deal with the results then you Itterate over the results.  I am not sure if this is the sort of thing you are asking or if I am way off with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper), an API that uses a convention-based matching algorithm to match up source to destination values in objects. Using this would presumably  remove most of your a = b.c code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll have to give that a shot on a project down the road, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented somthing like this with entityFramework:

```
//This returns an IQueryable of your Linq2Sql entities, here you put your query.
protected IQueryable<Team> GetTeamByIdQuery(Guid teamID)
{
    var qry = (from TeamsTable in db.Teams
               where blablabla.....
               select Teams;

    return qry;
}


//This will return your real entity
public IList<TeamBE> GetTeamById(Guid teamID)
{
    var query = this.GetTeamByIdQuery(teamID);
    IList<TeamBE> teams = ExecuteTeamQuery(query).toList<TeamBE>();

    return teams;
}


//this method will do the mapping from your L2S entities to your model entities
protected IQueryable<TeamBE> ExcuteTeamQuery(IQueryable<Team> query)
{
    return 
        query.select<Team, TeamBE> (team => 
           new TeamBE
           {
              TeamID = team.TeamID,
              Description = team.Description 
           }

}
```

Didn't test this much yet, but it works. I'm also working in a way to define which properties to load based on a bitflag parameter. I dont have it working yet but will be something like:

```
public IQueryable<TeamBE> ExcuteTeamQuery(IQueryable<Team> query, int loadLevel)
{
    return 
        query.select<Team, TeamBE> (team => 
           new TeamBE
           {
              TeamID = team.TeamID,
              TeamMembers = (HaveToLoad(LoadLevel.TeamMembers, loadLevel)) ? team.TeamMembers : null 
           }

}


enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Extension Methods:
if you have

```
public IQueryable<Team> GetTeams() { return db.Teams; }
```

Try writing:

```
public IQueryable<Team> WithDivisionId(this IQueryable<Team> qry, int divisionId)
{ return (from t in qry where t.DivisionId = divisionId select t);}
```

This way you can write Multiple extension methods that can query any `IQueryable<Team>` and layer them ...

To get teams from division 1 with 9 or more wins and a streak of 5 or more at some point you would just write:

```
GetTeams().WithDivisionId(1).HavingWonAtLeast(9).WithWinningStreak(5);
```

Comment: In case you didn't know, Linq Will generate the appropriate SQL statement based on ALL the filters and create a "final" query which it will execute - it doesn't fire off a query for EACH function.